# read subtext of an element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

how can i read value of this xpath **'/html/body/article/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[10]/div/div/text()[1]'** in java?

```
findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
```

i can access item via chrome extention but in java it fails saying no element found. i can only access like this; **'/html/body/article/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[10]/div/div'** but it is not what i want.

for example for this site: https://www.milliyet.com.tr/siyaset/canikli-kararlilikla-yurumeye-devam-ediyoruz-6277692

i would like to get these items text value separately

```
    /html/body/article/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[10]/div/div/text()[1]
    /html/body/article/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[10]/div/div/span/span[1]/time
    /html/body/article/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[10]/div/div/span/span[2]/time
```

thanks.

Comment: try method `getText()`

Comment: What does the source document look like? That content may not exist in the raw HTML that is returned, only created in JavaScript as the page loads, or the HTML elements may be in a namespace and then you would need to declare a namespace prefix and use it in your XPath.

Comment: This selector is simply not stable. The source is probably different during the test (because of clean session of the browser)

Comment: updated question with a sample

Answer (score 0):

`findElement ()` can only return the Web element which contains the text you may need. If you need the actual text within the element, you have to use getText() method. You will first need to find the element and use `getText()` method to retrieve the text.

```
WebElement myElement = findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/article/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[10]/div/div"));
System.out.println(myElement.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use relative XPath to fetch your data. You can use the 3 following XPath :

```
//div[@class='nd-article__info-block']
(//time[@datetime])[1]
(//time[@datetime])[2]
```

To extract the text, use `getText()` method :

```
string el1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='nd-article__info-block']")).getText();
string el2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//time[@datetime])[1]")).getText();
string el2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//time[@datetime])[2]")).getText();
```

You can also store the 3 results in a list  with a single XPath expression :

```
//div[@class='nd-article__info-block']|//time[@datetime]
```

Code :

```
List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='nd-article__info-block']|//time[@datetime]"));
List<String> els_text=new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){

        els_text.add(list.get(i).getText());
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());

    }
```